# Object.defineProperty polyfill

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, es5-shim

I am currently writing a JavaScript API which is based on new features in ES5. It uses `Object.defineProperty` quite extensively. I have wrapped this into two new functions, called `Object.createGetSetProperty` and `Object.createValueProperty`

I am however experiencing problems running this in older browsers (such as the dreaded, IE8)

Consider the following code:

```
Object.createGetSetProperty = function (object, property, get, set, enumerable, configurable) {
    if (!Object.defineProperty) throw new Error("Object.defineProperty is not supported on this platform");
    Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
        get: get,
        set: set,
        enumerable: enumerable || true,
        configurable: configurable || false
    });
};

Object.createValueProperty = function (object, property, value, enumerable, configurable, writable) {
    if (!Object.defineProperty) {
        object[property] = value;
    } else {
        Object.defineProperty(object, property, {
            value: value,
            enumerable: enumerable || true,
            configurable: configurable || false,
            writable: writable || false
        });
    }
};
```

As you can see, there is a graceful fallback under Object.createValueProperty, but I've no idea how to fallback gracefully with Object.createGetSetProperty.

Does anyone know of any solutions, shims, polyfills for this?

Comment: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties , They describe a polyfill at the end of the page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For clarity, you might want to stick with standard terminology and name your routines `defineDataProperty` and `defineAccessorProperty`.

Also, your `enumerable: enumerable || true` is going to result in a value of `true` even if the caller passes in false...

Anyway, to get down to the question at hand: you can't do this in IE8. It is said that `defineProperty` works in IE8 but only on DOM objects. There are ugly hacks for IE7 and below involving using the `onpropertychanged` event on DOM objects. All of this has been gone over in some detail in other questions, such as [Cross-browser Getter and Setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106936/cross-browser-getter-and-setter), [JavaScript getter support in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791267/javascript-getter-support-in-ie8), and many others.