# How to count characters in UI-Angular and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a app built with Angular and Angular UI. I am trying to count the characters across multiple accordions, as displayed in the plunker. The code I have only returns the first two characters and then nothing?

Is there something wrong I am doing?

The plunk is: [Example code](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFarBYLpDijPAr9QcrHS?p=preview)

app.js

```
$scope.what=[];
$scope.why=[];

Object.defineProperty($scope, 'characters', {
    get() {
        return $scope.what.length + $scope.why.length;
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
{{characters}}
```

But like I said this only returns the first two characters?

Comment: Because ```what``` and ```why``` are arrays. You're storing text at ```what[$index]``` but reading ```what```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why and what are arrays, if you want to count all the characters in these arrays, try :

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'characters', {
        get() {
            return $scope.what.join('').length + $scope.why.join('').length;
        }
});
```

Comment: Hi Thierry, The code above causes problems in IE and Safari - in safari i get SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
(anonymous function)controllers.js:38
angular.js:4373

Comment: @Sole what is the exact code in line 38 of controllers.js? I suppose there is a js function not supported in Safari?

Comment: its is: Object.defineProperty($scope, 'characters', {

Comment: Object.defineProperty doesn't work in IE8. May be your Safari version is very old? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271224/object-defineproperty-polyfill for workaround

Answer (score 0):

You could write up a function with a for loop to count the index of `what` and `why` and then place that in the AngularJS.