# Object.defineProperty is not a function

Tags: javascript, abap

I'm trying to execute JS code from ABAP and I'm getting the following error:

> Object.defineProperty is not a function.

My code:

```
Object.defineProperty(object, sProperty, vValue)
```

I want to redefine the funcion to be supported, any advice?

Comment: please add your code to the question.

Comment: [According to this](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_470/helpdata/en/49/a8e3c8d59811d4b2e90050dadfb92b/content.htm) ABAP supports only an antiquated version of JavaScript.

Comment: @JohannesJander i have updated my code

Comment: @Pointy yes i know and i want to use a funcion equivalent to Object.defineProperty which is supported by JS in abap

Comment: @ameni: There probably isn't any.

Comment: @vwegert, that one now is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's a nasty Chrome error bug.

This code:

```
Object.defineProperty({},'asd',{})()
```

..on Chrome throws:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty(...) is not a function
>       at :1:35

..but it should say that its the returned object of `Object.defineProperty` that is not a function.

---

For your case, it most probably mean that you are doing `()` (a function call) on the returned value of `Object.defineProperty`. And to fix it, the first return value of `defineProperty` must be a function, which means the first arg must be a function.

Answer (score -1):

#### Short answer:

Upgrade.

#### The answer you want:

Use a polyfill.
[Object.defineProperty polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271224/object-defineproperty-polyfill)