# Object.defineProperty alternative for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-8

Given javascript code like the following (extracted from a plugin referenced below):

```
var AutosizeInput = (function () {
    function AutosizeInput(input, options) {
        var _this = this;
        this._input = $(input);
        this._options = options;


    }
    Object.defineProperty(AutosizeInput.prototype, "options", {
        get: function () {
            return this._options;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
}
```

Full code of the plugin located at: https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input/blob/master/jquery.autosize.input.js

From what I read the call to Object.defineProperty will not work on IE8 as this is not a DOM object.

Is that accurate?..and if it is...which would be the best way to rewrite this getters (and setters) to be IE8 compliant?

Comment: In short, you can't. Possible duplicate of [JavaScript getter support in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791267/javascript-getter-support-in-ie8)

Comment: Why not simply use `options` instead of `_options`?

Comment: Does anybody know if `_defineGetter_` works in IE8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IE8 does not support getter/setter functions on properties of non DOM objects.

The "solution" here is to not rely on property getters, and use a full getter function instead.

```
AutosizeInput.prototype.getOptions = function() {
  return this._options;
};

var input = new AutoresizeInput();
input.getOptions();
```

Or, instead of keeping `this._options` as an "internal" variable, just drop the underscore allow access directly.  This way you need no magic at all.

```
var AutoresizeInput = function() {
  this.options = {};
}

var input = new AutoresizeInput();
input.options();
```

Comment: This actually worked...I guess I'll have to read more about javascript and different ways to define handle properties on an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own something like

```
 if (!Object.defineProperty) {
            Object.defineProperty = function (obj, prop, descriptor) {
                if (arguments.length < 3) { // all arguments required
                    throw new TypeError("Arguments not optional");
                }
                
                prop += ""; // convert prop to string
                ...
```

You can find the rest of the code here:

- https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-sham.js

Comment: The first link doesn't work, as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupGetter__ and the like aren't supported in IE8

Comment: Thanks, @bxk21. I will update the post accordingly