# Object.defineProperty is not working in IE8

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JSON Query language, project which is working fine in every browser except IE8.

I'm getting this `Object doesn't support this action` in IE8.

```
Object.defineProperty(FJQL, c, {
  get: function(){
    return (new Query(this, this.records))[c];
  }
});
```

Is there any alternative solution to this?

Thanks....

Comment: https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=defineproperty%20ie8

Answer (score 1):

`IE8 does not support getter/setter functions on properties of non DOM objects.`

So here you would need to use full getter functions

Please have a look through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175290/object-defineproperty-alternative-for-ie8).It gives you Answer.:)

Comment: Please vote/flag the question as duplicate next time, instead of posting an "answer".